# Handle large output - Python

Tags: python, amazon-s3, boto

I am using the python `boto` library to access files in a `S3` bucket. i have all the output sorted out and works fine. however I dont want to display all the files on the terminal at once. Say if a person has 800 files and 300 folders in their bucket, displaying all of them at once will be a mess as it wont be feasible to scroll through all of it. What would be the best way to display such large output? I was thinking about dividing them into pages but a little stuck up on the though process. Any help / ideas will be greatly appreciated

How I iterate over the list

```
for each in file_list:
    print ("{0} ,{1},{2},{3}".format(each.name,each.size,each.version)
```

EDIT:

I append the files into a list and print them out using a `for` loop to iterate over them and print them using `.format`. A sample looks like this:

```
Files
file1
file2
file3
file4
file5
file6
file7
file8
file9
file10
file11
file12
file13
file14
file15
file16

Folders:

folder1
folder2
folder3
folder4
folder5
folder6
folder7
folder8
```

Comment: so what is your problem with showing them as pages?

Comment: Not sure how to do it. I have though of putting all the records into a list. but  from there on how to show 10 (just an example) files per page

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can pipe the output to less (inside python using `subprocess`) to get the `less` command effect on your output.

Sample code:

```
import subprocess

long_array = []
for i in xrange(1000):
    line = 'Line text number {0}'.format(i)
    long_array.append(line)
output_string = '\n'.join(long_array)  # can be anything you want as long as it is a string

proc = subprocess.Popen('less', stdin=subprocess.PIPE)
proc.communicate(output_string)
```

Comment: Good idea, and if you add a full working example (e.g as a `showlonglist` function) I hope the OP can accept the then-complete answer.

Comment: @Boaz I have never used `subprocess`. Could you give me an example with my output?

Answer (score 0):

If you have or can install the `less` command (or the older but also workable `more`) @Boaz's idea of using it is no doubt best -- so you're probably OK on any Unix-like system.

But if you need or want to do it yourself more rudimentally:

```
def showlonglist(longlist, atatime=20):
    i = 0
    while i < len(longlist):
        for j in range(i, min(len(longlist)-1, i+atatime)):
            print(longlist[j])
        i += atatime
        print('Press Return to continue')
```

There are many more refined ways (such as using `iter` and then `itertools`) but this simplistic approach is appropriate for a somewhat rudimental situation in which you lack shell commands such as `less`.

Comment: I am using a `Mac` so I already have the less command installed.

Comment: Then you should accept @Boaz's answer (or at least needle him to actually provide a full working example of a `showlonglist` function using `less`, it's pretty easy, and needed for the answer to be complete:-).